# What is the mechanisms responsible for downregulation or loss of MHC-1 expression on the surface of cancer cells？

Tags: molecular-biology, cancer

Downregulation or loss of MHC-1 expression on the surface of cancer cells generally have been thought to be involved in the mechanism of immune escape.
It seems to be very attractive but I don't know the mechanisms of downregulation or loss of MHC-1 at cancer cells. Would you tell me the molecular mechanism,

Answer (score 1):

There is no single mechanism (as you'd expect, since there is no evolutionary relationship between different individuals' cancers).  The most common mechanisms are various forms of mutations, ranging from point mutations in single MHC molecules to large deletions of the MHC locus. Mutations in genes involved in antigen processing, that are not themselves part of the the MHC locus (e.g. TAP, b2-microglobulin), are also fairly common.  Epigenetic changes are also not uncommon.  There are several reasonably recent reviews, including

- [MHC Class I Antigen Processing and Presenting Machinery: Organization, Function, and Defects in Tumor Cells](http://jnci.oxfordjournals.org/content/105/16/1172.long)
- [Different regulation of MHC Class I antigen processing components in human tumors](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/15476910802482870)
- [The escape of cancer from T lymphocytes: immunoselection of MHC class I loss variants harboring structural-irreversible “hard” lesions](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00262-010-0893-2)

Comment: thanks for some reviews concerned with the topic.I will read them.